# Getting frequency response of my microphone

Tags: matlab, response, frequency, microphone, frequency-analysis

I'm trying to get a frequency response curve from a microphone that I have connected to my pc, using matlab.

I think I'm pretty close of getting the final code, but i think I'm missing something.

This is what I have right now:

```
close all, clear all, clc

x = 5;                        % seconds recording
Fs = 44100;                   % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;                     % Sample time                     
L= x*1000;                    % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;                % Time vector


% Record your voice for 'x' seconds.
recObj = audiorecorder(Fs, 24, 1);
disp('Start of Recording.');
recordblocking(recObj, x);
disp('End of Recording.');
% Store data in double-precision array.
myRecording = getaudiodata(recObj);

NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); % Next power of 2 from length of y
fourier = fft(myRecording);
Y = fft(myRecording,NFFT)/L;
f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
X = 2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1));
samples = get(recObj,'TotalSamples');

plot(f,X)  
title('Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum)
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('|Y(f)|')
```

This part of the code is correct I think. 
For example, when I play a tone of 5kHz I get this plot:
[image: this]

Now I play pink noise, and add this small part of code to convert it to dB, so I can get the frequency response curve:

```
dbX = db(X);
plot(f,dbX)
```

I expect (or my goal is..) a frequency response curve (as you can find on google images for example, I don't have enough reputation for more than 2 links, so sorry I didn't use a picture link here) , but I got this instead:

[image: this]

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what ..

Comment: Hum, I don't know much about this, but, why is that pink noise frequency plot wrong? what are you expecting?

Comment: My goal is to get something like this: http://www.acoustics.salford.ac.uk/acoustics_info/microphones/microphones_files/image013.jpg

Mine isn't even around 0dB, or not a flat line or something ..

Comment: That would be just a matter of scaling, the signal. Also note that the plot says 'relative response'.

Answer (score 0):

You are closer than you think. Here are three tips to get a little closer.

Firstly, you need a logarithmic plot of your frequency domain data. Use `semilogx()` instead of plot.

Secondly, you're going to need to smooth the data. The simplest function for this in Matlab is `smooth()` but there are more advanced options that may better suit your needs.

Finally, in order to get a relative response, subtract the mean from your data. `dbx_relative = dbx-mean(dbx)`

Putting it all together:

```
dbX = db(X); 
relative_dbx = dbx-mean(dbx); 
smoothed_dbx = smooth(relative_dbx); 
semilogx(f,smoothed_dbx);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pwelch` to compute the transfer function between the stimulus signal (i.e. the reference audio waveform ) and the response (what you measure with your microphone).